# Poor label and legend resolution using MaTeX

Tags: legending, labeling, latex, matex

I am using Mathematica 12.3 and the MaTeX package in order to typeset my labels and legends correctly. I get quite blurry text and I don't know if there is a way to improve the resolution of the generated text. My code is

```
EntropyPlotr0Finite = 
 Legended[Show[
   Join[Table[
     ListPlot[EntropyForr0[[i]], PlotStyle -> ColorList[[i]], 
      PlotMarkers -> {MarkersList[[i]], Small}], {i, 1, 4}], 
    Table[Plot[fitsForr0[[i]][x], {x, 0.1, 5}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Thickness -> 0.002, Orange}], {i, 1, 4}]], 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> {MaTeX["\\textbf{r}\\boldsymbol{_0}", 
      FontSize -> 20], MaTeX["\\boldsymbol{S_N}", FontSize -> 20]}, 
   LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Italic, FontSize -> 17], 
   ImageSize -> 800], 
  Placed[Framed[
    Column[{PointLegend[
       ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[;; 2]], {Style[
         MaTeX["\\textbf{Values of }\\boldsymbol{S_N}\\textbf{ for \
}\\boldsymbol{\\kappa_m=0.1}", FontSize -> 14]]}, 
       LegendMarkerSize -> 15, 
       LegendMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle], 10}], 
      PointLegend[{Red}, {Style[
         MaTeX["\\textbf{Values of }\\boldsymbol{S_N}\\textbf{ for \
}\\boldsymbol{\\kappa_{m+1}\\textbf{ from Eq.}}", FontSize -> 14]]}, 
       LegendMarkerSize -> 15, 
       LegendMarkers -> {\[SixPointedStar], 10}], 
      PointLegend[{Orange}, {Style[
         MaTeX["\\textbf{Values of }\\boldsymbol{S_N}\\textbf{ for \
}\\boldsymbol{\\kappa_{m+2}\\textbf{ from Eq.}}", FontSize -> 14]]}, 
       LegendMarkerSize -> 15, 
       LegendMarkers -> {\[FilledSquare], 10}], 
      PointLegend[{Black}, {Style[
         MaTeX["\\textbf{Values of }\\boldsymbol{S_N}\\textbf{ for \
}\\boldsymbol{\\kappa_{m+3}\\textbf{ from Eq.}}", FontSize -> 14]]}, 
       LegendMarkerSize -> 15, 
       LegendMarkers -> {\[FilledUpTriangle], 10}]}], 
    RoundingRadius -> 5], {1, 0.6}]]
```

and the resulting image after exporting it with

```
Export["EntropyPlotr0.pdf", EntropyPlotr0Finite, 
 ImageResolution -> 2000]
```

looks like: [image]
In particular the legend looks like:
[image]
which isn't the best quality.

Comment: If you have problems with some software, the first thing to try is always to upgrade to the latest version! Do this and it will fix it.

Comment: I just tried your example and am getting device independent resolution--with my updated version of Szabolcs package.  I was having a similar problem before I downloaded SH's newest version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because Mathematica 12.2 and later import PDFs as raster images by default.

MaTeX 1.7.8, released October 2020, is updated to be compatible with Mathematica 12.2 and later. Please upgrade to the latest MaTeX version.